# Lua : copying a table efficiently (deep copy)

Tags: lua, arguments, parameter-passing, deep-copy, pass-by-reference-value

I try to make efficiently a copy of a lua table. I have written the following function copyTable() that works well (see below). But I imagined I could have something more efficient using the "passing by value" mechanism of the functions. I made a few tests to explore this mechanism :

```
function nop(x)
  return x
end

function noop(x)
  x={}
  return x
end

function nooop(x)
  x[#x+1]=4
  return x
end

function copyTable(datatable)
  local tblRes={}
  if type(datatable)=="table" then
    for k,v in pairs(datatable) do tblRes[k]=copyTable(v) end
  else
    tblRes=datatable
  end
  return tblRes
end

tab={1,2,3}
print(tab)            -->table: 0x1d387e0 tab={1,2,3}
print(nop(tab))       -->table: 0x1d387e0 tab={1,2,3}
print(noop(tab))      -->table: 0x1e76f90 tab={1,2,3}
print(nooop(tab))     -->table: 0x1d387e0 tab={1,2,3,4}
print(tab)            -->table: 0x1d387e0 tab={1,2,3,4}
print(copyTable(tab)) -->table: 0x1d388d0
```

We can see that the reference to the table is transferred unchanged through the functions (when I just read it or add things) except within noop() where I try a radical modification of the existing.

I read [Bas Bossink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74198/bas-bossink) and the answer made by [Michael Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221955/michael-anderson) in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128152/function-variable-scope-pass-by-value-or-reference). Regarding the passing or tables as arguments, they emphasized the difference between "arguments passed by ref" and "arguments passed by values and tables are references" with examples where this difference appears.

But what does that mean precisely ? Do we have a copy of the reference, but what difference does that make with a passing through ref since the data pointed and therefore manipulated is still the same, not copied ? Is the mechanism in noop() specific when we try to affect nil to the table, specific to avoid the deletion of the table or in which cases does it trigger (we can see with nooop() that it is not always the case when the table is modified) ?

My question : how the mechanism of passing tables really works ? Is there a way to make a more efficient way to copy the data of a table without the burden of my copyTable ?

Comment: Recursion and tailcalls. That's as efficient as you'll get.

Comment: @warspyking : Would I gain much in speed, in space ? How shall I "qualify" for tail call when I need to assemble sub-tables ?

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of argument passing in Lua is similarly to C: ***everything*** is pass by value, but tables and userdata are passed around as pointers. Passing a copy of a reference does not appear so different in usage, but it is completely different than passing by reference.

For example, you brought this part up specifically.

```
function noop(x)
  x={}
  return x
end
print(noop(tab))      -->table: 0x1e76f90 tab={1, 2, 3}
```

You are assigning the value for the new table[1] into variable `x` (`x` now holds a new pointer value). You didn't mutate the original table, the `tab` variable still holds the pointer value to the original table. When you return from `noop` you are passing back the value of the new table, which is empty. *Variables hold values, and a pointer is a value, not a reference.*

## Edit:

Missed your other question. No, if you want to deep-copy a table, a function similar to what you wrote is the only way. Deep copies are *very* slow when tables get large. To avoid performance issues, you might use a mechanism like *"rewind tables"*, which keep track of changes made to them so they can be undone at later points in time (very useful in recursive with backtrack contexts). Or if you just need to keep users from screwing with table internals, write a *"freezable"* trait.

[1] Imagine the `{}` syntax is a function that constructs a new table and returns a pointer to the new table.

Comment: I then understand the difference between "arguments passed by ref" and "arguments passed by values and tables are references" : as long as I use the pointer, by reading x.foo or by affecting x.foo="foo" for instance, everything is very much the same as passing by ref. The difference with ref is that I can re-affect x, for instance by x={}, thing I couldn't do with a reference. Correct ?

Comment: That's absolutely correct. A reference is an alias for a *variable* not a variable holding the same value. For example, in C++, you can't assign a new object to a reference because of that fact. But if you used pointers instead, you could change the pointer, because pointers are values. It's a subtle difference, but a useful one. Lua uses pointer semantics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that those 3 assumptions (A) are valid for "tab" (the table being copied):

1. There are no table keys

   ```
   t1 = {}
   tab = {}
   tab[t1] = value
   ```
2. There are no repeated table values

   ```
   t1 = {}
   tab = {}
   tab.a = t1
   tab.b = t1
   -- or
   -- tab.a.b...x = t1
   ```
3. There are no recursive tables:

   ```
   tab = {}
   tab.a = tab
   -- or
   -- tab.a.b...x = tab
   ```

Then the code you provided is the smallest and almost as efficient as possible.

If A1 doesn't hold (i.e. you have table keys), then you must change your code to:

```
function copyTable(datatable)
  local tblRes={}
  if type(datatable)=="table" then
    for k,v in pairs(datatable) do 
      tblRes[copyTable(k)] = copyTable(v) 
    end
  else
    tblRes=datatable
  end
  return tblRes
end
```

If A2 doesn't hold (i.e. you have repeated table values), then you could change your code to:

```
function copyTable(datatable, cache)
  cache = cache or {}
  local tblRes={}
  if type(datatable)=="table" then
    if cache[datatable] then return cache[datatable]
    for k,v in pairs(datatable) do 
      tblRes[copyTable(k, cache)] = copyTable(v, cache) 
    end
    cache[datatable] = tblRes
  else
    tblRes=datatable
  end
  return tblRes
end
```

This approach only pays off, though, if you have lots of repeated large tables. So, it is a matter of evaluating which version is faster for your actual production scenario.

If A3 doesn't hold (i.e. you have recursive tables), then your code (and both adjustments above) will enter an infinite recursive loop and eventually throw a stack overflow.

The simplest way to handle that is keeping a backtrack and throwing an error if table recursion happens:

```
function copyTable(datatable, cache, parents)
  cache = cache or {}
  parents = parents or {}
  local tblRes={}
  if type(datatable)=="table" then
    if cache[datatable] then return cache[datatable]
    assert(not parents[datatable])
    parents[datatable] = true
    for k,v in pairs(datatable) do 
      tblRes[copyTable(k, cache, parents)]
        = copyTable(v, cache, parents) 
    end
    parents[datatable] = false
    cache[datatable] = tblRes
  else
    tblRes=datatable
  end
  return tblRes
end
```

My solution for a deepcopy function which handles recursive tables, preserving the original structure may be found here: https://gist.github.com/cpeosphoros/0aa286c6b39c1e452d9aa15d7537ac95

Comment: interesting to have a function "out of the box" to perform the deepcopy in various contexts. Could you explain what are the variables of the function deepCopy(value, cache, promises, copies) or/and and a working example ?