# Stuck on a basic Lua writeInteger function

Tags: lua

I am a newcomer to coding in general and I want to learn basic Lua scripting for my own hobby.
After working on a Lua script, the syntax all seems to be without error but I have come across one issue that I don't understand, I broke it down to this basic function:

```
{$lua}
 ID1 = "10"
 ID2 = "0"

if (ID1 ~= nil and ID1 == "10") then
  writeInteger(ID2,"25")
  end

print(ID2)
```

The issue is that the writeInteger does not seem to work at all, ID2 remains at value "0" while it should become "25".
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nobody knows what writeInteger is supposed to do, what arguments it expects etc.

Comment: Would you please mind elaborating? I am completely clueless on it

Comment: Where are you running your Lua script? Is it for Lua embedded in a game, for one of the microcontrollers that uses Lua, for a standalone Lua script, or something else? We will need some more details to work out where the writeInteger function comes from, etc.

Comment: It is from a hex editor called Cheat Engine.
You get a list of addresses in an application where you can use writeInteger(address,value) to rewrite a particular value

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid Lua, or at least it isn't valid vanilla (out-of-the-box) Lua, and since you have not specified anything else, there is not much we can do to help. I will assume `writeInteger` is a valid function (since your interpreter isn't complaining about a call to a nil value), but I don't think it works as you expect.

If you want to set the `ID2` variable to `25`, simply write:

```
ID2 = 25
```

Lua will convert the string type to an integer type automatically. You can run `print(type(ID2))` to confirm this

If you are using cheat engine (as a quick google search suggests) the writeInteger function requires an address and a value.

```
function writeInteger(Address, Value): Boolean - Returns true on success.
```

I am not sure if `ID2`, a Lua variable, is a valid address, but I am sure that `"25"` is not an integer. You should remove the quotation marks to start, and since the function returns a boolean you can see if the function was successful by doing:

```
print(writeInteger(ID2, 25))
```

Comment: It is a Cheat Engine script, yes
ID2 is a variable that changes, and when it becomes a certain number it should trigger a writeInteger function meaning it should write a value based on a specified calculation.

I was not aware writeInteger was not part of vanilla Lua.
I also figured out I can call a value from somewhere based on a description, but sadly I do not know if there is a way to write back to that value in the same manner, only by writing to the actual address.

Answer (score 0):

Lua uses pass by value for primitive types like numbers, booleans and strings. So if you pass a number to a function like writeInteger, it creates a local copy within the function. The function can alter this copy but it will have no effect on caller (of writeInteger in this case). I don't know how writeInteger is supposed to work but if you want to call a function which alters its argument you can create a table and pass that. Tables are still passed by value but the "value" of a table is its memory address (so in effect tables are passed by reference and you can alter the contents of a table by passing it to a function).

See more here
[Function/variable scope (pass by value or reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128152/function-variable-scope-pass-by-value-or-reference)